# React Native: How to get a "normal" SelectBox/Picker

Tags: react-native, picker

I started with React Native a few days ago. Developing for Android is nice because of existing tools/simulators (Linux) and I am using Android for years on my mobile and tablet.

Because I do not have a Mac I bought an older iPhone for testing my first apps on iOS too.

So I was pretty astonished when I saw what a Picker looks like on iOS (this sort of twist wheel thing).

Is there any way to get a Picker that is more like HTMLs Select or the Android Picker?

Comment: try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@technicalbros/react-native-floating-inputs

Comment: but it lacks of documentation, you'll need to look at the component's source code

Comment: Have you looked into react-native-picker-select? https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select#readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select

very popular and it works very well